# How do i properly create class Ratio add(Ratio r)?

Tags: java

For my homework assignment, I was given skeleton code and told to fill in the classes so that they work properly when it comes to adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing a fraction. I need help understanding how exactly the Ratio r works? My teacher told me "It carries the values to complete the calculation with the numerator and denominator "this" carries"?

Based on what he said, I feel that my math itself is correct, just not sure of how to return r?

I've tried to play around with the Ratio "r" but I cant seem to figure out how it works.

The way I currently have set r equal to isn't working, it says "cannot convert from type long to ratio"

```
// class level variables
private long _numerator;
private long _denominator;

public Ratio()
{
    long _numerator = 0;
    long _denominator = 1;


}// end of Ratio()

public Ratio(long a)
{
    a = 0;
    _denominator = 1;

}// end of Ratio(long a)

public Ratio(long dividend, long divisor) throws ArithmeticException
{

    this._numerator = dividend;

    // check denominator for 0
    if (divisor == 0)
    {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Denominator cannot be zero");
    } else
        this._denominator = divisor;
    // check for negative
    if (dividend < 0 && divisor < 0) // if there's a negative in numerator and denominator, fraction becomes
                                        // positive
    {
        dividend *= -1;
        divisor *= -1;
    } else if (divisor < 0) // if negative is in denominator, moves negative to the numerator
    {
        dividend *= -1;
        divisor *= -1;
    }

    // simplify fraction in here using gcd
    gcd(dividend, divisor);

}// end of Ratio(long dividend...)

long getNumerator()
{
    return _numerator;
}

long getDenominator()
{
    return _denominator;
}

public Ratio add(Ratio r)
{

    long num= this._numerator;
    long den = this._denominator;
    long otherDen = getDenominator();
    long otherNum = getNumerator(); 
    r = new Ratio();

    //is this the return way to do it?
    r = ((num * otherDen) + (otherNum * den)) / (den * otherDen);

    //or do i have to seperate numerator & denominator?
    long newNum = ((num * otherDen) + (otherNum * den));
    long newDen = (den * otherDen);

    return r();
}// end of add
```

Comment: Actually, it's not clear what you need.Ratio is your own class or from Java package? Where do you have problem? With `r = new Ratio();` and after that?

Comment: @Dred, I believe its my own class. I'm having trouble trying to take the calculations " r = ((num * otherDen) + (otherNum * den)) / (den * otherDen);" and trying to return them in the proper format

Comment: Also, the public class is titled " public class Ratio implements comparable.

Comment: Firstly,you can't return `return r();` only `return r;`  Also,your exception is happened , because you try do that `Ratio=((long*long)+(long*long))/(long*long);` You can't equals Ratio with long, it's different types.

Comment: @Dred so what is type ratio?

Comment: @Corinne Bond I think you have to write code for `add(Radio r)` mehod ... Right?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as your `Ratio` object contains two fields, you have to fill them with your newly calculated numerator and denominator, and the simply return the object `new Ratio(resultNumerator, resultDenominator)`.

```java
public Ratio add(Ratio r) {
    long otherDen = getDenominator();
    long otherNum = getNumerator(); 
    long resultDenominator = this._denominator * otherDen;
    long resultNumerator = this._numerator * otherDen + otherNum * this._denominator;

    return new Ratio(resultNumerator, resultDenominator);
}
```